# How to pass parameters from parent activity to child tabs in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native and looking if someone could direct me in detail how to pass parameters to a child tab.

I researched already and found that it could be done using screenprops, however none of those gave me a clear understanding on how to use it to pass the parameters. A clean sample code could be beneficial.

Comment: you should read this before posting your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy you have not look around enough there are lots of packages, I recommend you to use following package, and take a look at following example. Next time research information that you need before you ask something.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabView, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

import SceneA from './SceneA';
import SceneB from './SceneB';

class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: 'active', title: 'Scene A' },
        { key: 'inactive', title: 'Scene B' },
      ],
    };

    this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this);
    this.renderLabel = this.renderLabel.bind(this);
    this.onTabChange = this.onTabChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTabChange(index) {
    this.setState({ index });
  }

  // Here you can send props to different tab components 
  renderScene({ route }) {
    if (!route.key) return null;

    if (route.key === 'active') {
      return <SceneA type="active" />; // SceneA specific props here
    }

    if (route.key === 'inactive') {
      return <SceneB type="inactive" />;
    }
  }

  renderLabel({ route }, props) {
    const { index } = this.state;
    const selected = route.key === props.navigationState.routes[index].key;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {route.title.toUpperCase()}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderTab() {
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        onIndexChange={this.onTabChange}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        renderTabBar={props => (
          <TabBar
            {...props}
            renderLabel={e => this.renderLabel(e, props)}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderTab()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```